# Adding Redirects programmatically to React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to add a bunch of redirects given an array of old routes and new routes so I came out with this component:

```js
const redirectUrls = [
    { oldUrl: '/robin', newUrl: '/users' },
    { oldUrl: '/batman', newUrl: '/courses' }
];

export default Redirects = () => (
    redirectUrls.map((url, index) => <Route key={index} exact path={url.oldUrl} render={() => <Redirect to={url.newUrl} />} />)
);
```

Which works fine, but I wanted it to be simplier so I removed the `Route` and left only the redirect like this:

```js
export default Redirects = () => (
    redirectUrls.map((url, index) => <Redirect key={index} exact from={url.oldUrl} to={url.newUrl} />))
```

But it won't work, all the redirects take me to the last route, which in this case is `/courses`, and its weird because if I do this:

```js
<Switch>
    ...
    <Route path='/users' exact component={users} />
    <Route path="/courses" exact component={CoursesList} />
    <Redirect from='/robin' to='/users' />
    <Redirect from='/batman' to='/courses' /> // having them like this works fine
</Switch>
```

So it makes no sense for them fail when I create them with a map and I haven't found anything that leads to the cause nor to a solution.

Comment: can you show how your routes looks like in your react dev tool ? a screenshot may be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the exported redirects in a switch:

```
const Redirects = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {redirectUrls.map(url => (
        <Redirect from={url.oldUrl} to={url.newUrl} />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Redirects;
```

That's only if you actually need to make a component out of them. It's not totally clear what you need and are looking for since `export default Redirects = () =>` is invalid syntax. If you just want to bundle them as some variable you can do:

```
export const Redirects = redirectUrls.map(url => <Redirect from={url.oldUrl} to {url.newUrl} />);

// App.js

<Switch>
    <Route path='/users' exact component={users} />
    <Route path="/courses" exact component={CoursesList} />
    ...
    {Redirects}
</Switch>
```

Comment: Why adding another Switch to the redirects makes the map work? If having them one by one with one switch works fine.
Also this `export default Redirects = ()` is valid, even though the `Redirects` is unnecessary.

Comment: To be honest I'm not totally sure. I've used this as a workaround in the past but after playing with it some more it doesn't always behave as I expected it to. For instance, putting in a similar component of mapped `Routes` (no Switch) above the mapped `Redirects` component makes the redirects stop working. Placing the `Redirects` component at the top of the parent switch also breaks the rest of the routes for me. I'm not sure I can recommend using this method anymore, at least not without some clarification - the github issues page might be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with exact props

```
<Switch>
  ...
    <Route path='/users' exact component={users} />
    <Route path="/courses" exact component={CoursesList} />
    <Redirect exact from='/robin' to='/users' />
    <Redirect exact from='/batman' to='/courses' /> // having them like this works fine
</Switch>
```

Reference https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4837

Comment: Yeap I did try it, that code you posted actually works the issue is when I do it with a map